# How do I show that this $p$-adic function is surjective modulo $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime. Let $f: \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Z}_p$ be surjective modulo $p^n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, where $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the set of $p$-adic integers.

If it is given that $g: \{0,1,\ldots,p-1\} \to \{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$ is defined as

$$g(i) = \frac{f(m+ ip^{1+\lfloor \log_p m\rfloor }) - f(m)}{p^{1+ \lfloor \log_p m\rfloor }} \text{ (mod } p) $$

How do I show that $g$ is also surjective?

I am planning to show $g$ represents all elements of $\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$ so that it is onto.

However $g$ being a modulo of a fraction makes it confusing for me.

Comment: What is $m$ --?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg $m \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: So $g$ depends on a parameter $m$? And it's supposed to be shown for each $m$?

Comment: Apparently yes.

Answer (score 1):

Without further conditions on $f$, and the way you want the dependence on $m$ be interpreted as per comment, this is wrong. Example: Let $p \neq 2$ and

$$f(x) := \begin{cases} \dfrac{1}{p}\log(x) \quad \text{ if } x \equiv 1 \text{ mod } p \\
0 \qquad \qquad \text{ otherwise } \end{cases}$$

Then if $m \not\equiv 1$ mod $p$, the formula gives $g(i)=0$ for all $i$.

Some things are strange in the question , namely, $f$ being "surjective mod $p^n$ for all $n$" is the same as just saying it is surjective; and I still find the dependence on $m$ weird, as noted in a comment.

Also, the formula for $g$ looks like a difference quotient, but I do not see how that would be of any help, why would anyone be interested in surjectivity mod $p$ of that expression? Maybe can you give some context and motivation?

Comment: I guess $f \in \mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]$ and $p \ge 3$ so that  $f(m+i p^n+O(p^{n+1})) = f(m)+i p^n f'(m)+O(p^{n+1})$

Comment: @reuns I see, that's a little more interesting indeed. For the conclusion in the OP we still need $f'(m) \in \Bbb Z_p^\times$, right?

Comment: Yes and it follows from surjectiveness. If $f'(m) \not \in \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ then we need $f \in p^{-d} \mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]$ to obtain $\mathbb{Z}_p \subset f(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ but then $f(\mathbb{Z}_p) \subset \mathbb{Z}_p$ iff $d\ge 0$